# VBA Handle events with website login

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm writing a macro to access a webpage after the user enters their login ID/Password. I've added code to exit the sub if either of those fields are left empty - but how would I handle the event that the log-in doesn't work? Currently, it just brings them to the website login page but I would rather have the login code loop until the login works.

Any ways of doing this? I'm not familiar with Internet Controls.

The login part of my code looks like this:

```
Set SupDOC = SupIE.document
With SupDOC.forms(0)
    .j_username.Value = InputBox("To Login Dun & Bradstreet, Enter your D&B Username/Email: ")
    If .j_username.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Username was entered."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    .j_password.Value = InputBox("To Login Dun & Bradstreet, Enter your D&B Password: ")
    If .j_password.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Password was entered."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    .submit
End With
```

EDIT:

Sometimes the login times-out and after submitting correct login-information, the site redirects to "Session has timed out" and the requires login again. After logging in, the site doesn't load to the page that I specify later. Any ideas on fixing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put these loops after the login submission, and navigation to new site and solved any issues with redirection. This is dependant on the website but this gets around the "Session timed out" for me.

```
Do While SupIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until SupIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

After you submit it, you could do a loop to wait for the ReadyState to get back to 4, then check if the fields are empty then go to the top and try again until it works.

EDIT: Define URL as a string, if you get redirected, it will navigate to the login page.

```
URL = SupIE.LocationURL

TryAgain:

    Set SupDOC = SupIE.document
    With SupDOC.forms(0)
        .j_username.Value = InputBox("To Login Dun & Bradstreet, Enter your D&B Username/Email: ")
        If .j_username.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "No Username was entered."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .j_password.Value = InputBox("To Login Dun & Bradstreet, Enter your D&B Password: ")
        If .j_password.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "No Password was entered."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .submit

        Do While SupIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        If .j_username.Value = "" Or .j_password.Value = "" Then GoTo TryAgain:

        If InStr(SupDOC.DocumentElement.outerText, "Session timed") Then
            SupIE.navigate URL
            Do While SupIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            GoTo TryAgain:
        End If

    End With
```

Comment: What does ReadyState 4 define? (I didn't know there were different readystate states).

Also, does this loop if an invalid login was entered?

Comment: Just tested the code, no matter what I type in, it prompts the message box

Comment: IE has 4 ready states, essentially each of them represent a different load state of the page, 1 being not loaded at all, 4 being completely loaded and you're able to interact and everything. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534361(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What happens when you F8 through the code? Assuming it redirects you to the login page with nothing in the UN/PW fields, it should loop back to the beginning.

Comment: After F8, it highlights the Sub (yellow arrow).

Comment: Step through it and see where it gets stuck or loops back to the beginning. It should be filling out the username/password, then submitting it, waiting for the page to load and going back to the beginning if the username/password were in correct or if you get redirected, it loads the original URL and starts from the beginning.